# copy files within subdirectories to temp folder where only 1 file extension exists

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have subdirectories like this:

```
dir1/
 1a.txt
 1a.out
 1b.txt
dir2/
 2a.txt
 2b.txt
 2b.out
```

where i want to copy files where only 1 file type exists within that subdirectory. i.e. in this case I would want to copy `1b.txt` and `2a.txt` to a tmp folder.

I can guarantee that a `.txt` appears for each file, but sometime a `.out` does not. Basically I just want to find those files with a `.txt` but their `.out` equivalent does not exist.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? This could be done with 2 nested `for` loops imo

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple version of the double loop mentioned by Aserre:

```
for d in dir?
do for f in $d/*.txt
   do [[ -e ${f%.txt}.out ]] && continue || cp "$f" tmp/
   done
done
```

This only copies *.txt's, so you'd have to check separately or complicate the condition a bit if you also wanted *.out files that have no matching *.txt, but it should give you something to work with.

c.f. the rules for [Parameter Substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PARAMSUBREF) and [Manipulating Strings](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) for explanations and more toys.

Note that this makes no effort to handle special characters or spaces embedded in filenames.